# is there is way to use only one function to insert for all diifferent table in php codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller, sql-insert

```
public function insert($data = array()) {
      $this->db->insert('tablename',$data);
      return $this->db->affected_rows() == 1 ? true : false ;
  }
```

can we use only one function to insert to multiple table from different,
i.e i have 3 module like customer, product, sales.
instead of writing 3 insert function for all 3 modules
can we use the one insert function to insert into database

Comment: @RakeshSharma can you show the example, it will be most helpfull

Comment: @RakeshSharma  this approach is really good, just want to know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to pass `table name` in function form controller

**IN models**

```
 function insert($table,$data = array()) {
          $this->db->insert($table,$data);// common insert function 
          return $this->db->affected_rows() == 1 ? true : false ;
      }
```

**IN controller**

For example

```
$data = array('name' => $name, 'email' => $email, 'url' => $url);// create data for each tabale

$this->model->insert('customer',$data);// pass table name form controller
```

Comment: Yes we can . Update and delete need where condition .

Comment: how do we use in the update  and delete function, how to satisfy the where condition

Comment: What is the way of doing this in case of  **query binding** ?